# What really causes cancer?

Tags: cancer

A lot of things are claimed to cause cancer, eating red meat, eggs, smoking, using phones, deodorant, breathing.

Surely these can't all actually *significantly* contribute to the development of cancer.

I've heard smoking is a big one to lung cancer, with someone--I can't recall--saying that most patients with this cancer are smokers.

What kind of activities/foods are sure to, or have high chances to, lead to the development of cancerous cells and how do they cause them, at a molecular level?

Comment: Do you want to know which chemical causes cancer? Or what is the general reason behind cancer?

Comment: What really causes cancer: mutations in certain genes.

Comment: @chris Chemicals, and thus activities/foods.

Comment: "Cancer" is not just a single disease. *Cancers* would be more accurate, but even that doesn't do justice to the vast array of different kinds of cancers at the genetic or molecular level.

Comment: As they say, in California, EVERYTHING causes cancer :p

Comment: @kmm brings up a good point. As such, this question is *way* too broad. Tobi, I recommend that you edit this question to focus on a particular type of cancer (e.g., perhaps lung cancer like you already mention). I also recommend doing a bit more research on your own and updating your question w/ what you find. Doing both of those things should reduce the chance that this question gets closed. For more help writing good questions, see [here](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). Thanks!

Comment: I've sufficiently edited the question, I'd really like a proper answer.

Comment: [The Guardian: The 116 things that can give you cancer – the full list](https://www.theguardian.com/society/2015/oct/28/116-things-that-can-give-you-cancer-list)

Comment: @Tobi - No, this is way too broad. You may have specified one organ system, but you're still asking for a definitive list. "What kind of activities/foods are sure to, or have high chances to, lead to the development of cancerous cells and how do they cause them, at a molecular level?" Can't be done for a number of reasons. Kind of like asking "What do I have to do to roll a 12 three times in a row with fair dice?" Answer: there is no answer to that question, because the outcome of fair dice cannot be predicted if thrown properly.

Answer (score -3):

Cancer is caused by the mutations in cells.

Cancer exists because of the failure of cell cycle checks which could actually allow cells to survive with erratic genomes. However, that alone does not cause cancer.

Cancer is the uncontrolled proliferation of cells. That only happens when cells have accumulated enough errors during cell division and each cell division goes undetected to the point that cells refuse to commit apoptosis; they are no longer receptive to the body's control mechanisms.

Cancer cells are also malignant. That means that cancer cells cannot be called cancer cells until they are invasive. That means a few cancerous cells cannot be caused cancer because they don't take nutrients from the body . Also, tumour  suppressor  genes can also cause cancer when they turn proto-oncogenes into oncogenes.

Comment: "please tell me if what are said here is factually true." While it's great that you're looking for feedback, you shouldn't post an answer you're unsure of. There are, however, a lot of interesting facts here that are sure to be helpful to the OP. Please provide a source for those who want to do further reading.

Comment: You have missed the very numerous benign cancers, which, though not invasive, are still cancer.  Also, invasive doesn't quite mean what you think it means.

Comment: You are correct in that cancer is a result of escaping cell cycle checks. This is usually a result of mutations. Not always.  See mesothelioma resulting from asbestos exposure. There are some cancers that seem to be a combination of genetic and epigenetic mechanisms. Further, you can have cancer cells that have not become invasive. This is what a tumor is before it acquires the ability to extravasate and set up shop elsewhere. That is metastasis. Further confusing the issue, a benign tumor IS uncontrolled proliferation, but usually considered "non-cancerous" (can't metastasize).

Comment: @akaDrHouse - "...benign tumor IS uncontrolled proliferation, but usually considered "non-cancerous" (can't metastasize)" I disagree. The ability to metastasize is not what defines a cancer. It is what defines a metastatic tumor from a benign tumor. I can name dozens of cancers that don't metastasize.

Comment: Thanks guys for being so negative. I'm quitting stack exchange. At least I tried to help

Comment: Thanks for the correction @anongoodnurse. You are right. I was confusing malignant and metastasis. I will change my comment. Edit: it won't let me.